# How to represent quotes in an animated graph?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I made an excel file with more than 5,000 derogatory quotes (date, insult, target, twitter link) made by an individual on Twitter.

I would like to make a Youtube video of it.

This video would show his daily insults from 2016 to 2019. Each day we would see the targeted person and the insult.

Plus, I want to include two other graphs showing the most targeted person and another graph showing the most used insults.

It would look like something like this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4-2nqd6-ZXg

How to represent this the more clearly possible ? Bar charts ?

Comment: What is the information that you want to show? How many insults each target gets? How often he uses the same insult? First, you should think how you would show the data and what you want to tell the viewer.

Comment: Are you asking how to create animated graphs or are you asking for ways to represent the data?

Comment: @AndrewH Yeah, I want to know that too.  Video editing is off-topic here. More suited to Video Production Stack Exchange.

Comment: Hello everyone, thank you for your replies. I want to know how to represent the data. The video will show: who gets insulted each day,  the most used insult and the most targeted persons.

Comment: This, unfortunately, seems to amount to "idea farming" which isn't really what this site is about.